# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning: Unhandled promise rejection.
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().
I can't Post Data into Mongodb.
I am getting this error:  Post validation failed: content: Path `content` is required., title: Path `title` is required.

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

const postSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    // id:{type:String},
    title:{type:String,required: true},
    content:{type:String,required:true}
})

module.exports=mongoose.model('Post',postSchema);
```

```
const express=require('express');

const mongoose=require('mongoose');

const app=express();
//Pwz9u2u5ELbDvISQ
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://root:Pwz9u2u5ELbDvISQ@cluster0.d9ggt.mongodb.net/node-angular?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
,{  useNewUrlParser: true ,useUnifiedTopology: true })
   .then(()=>{
console.log('Connected To Database');
   })
.catch(()=>{
    console.log('Connection Failed');
})
const Post=require('./models/post')
 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-Width,Content-Type,Accept"
    )
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    "Get,POST,PATCH,DELETE, OPTIONS"
    )
    next();
})

app.post('/api/posts',(req,res,next)=>{
    const post=new Post();
    
   title:req.body.title;
    content:req.body.content; 
    
    post.save();

    console.log("Post are :"+post);
    
    res.status(201).json({
        message:'Post Added Sucess'
    });
})



app.get('/api/posts',(req,res,next)=>{
  const posts=[
     {id:'fadf112345',
     title:'First server-side post',
     content:'This is some content kindly forget what you just saw '
    },
    {id:'Yopadf112345',
    title:'SECOND server-side post',
    content:'That  is some content kindly forget what you just saw '
   }  
  ]
    res.status(200).json({
        message :'Post Fetched Sucuess!',
        posts:posts 
    })
})

module.exports=app;
```

Comment: `post.save()`. This looks unhandled like the error says.  Also doing a status 201 before the record is saved is not a good idea.

Comment: @Keith What do you suggest ? post.save() is necessary to push data in mongodb.

Comment: I'm not saying you don't save, I'm saying you need to handle it..  `post.save().then(....).catch(....)`.  And your 201 wants to go in the `then` part and ideally you want to send an error on catch bit..